# jqplot set custom color for pie charts based on label name

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors, jqplot

To plot my data I'm using jqplot. I wish I could set a specific color on my pie chart according to the label values.
For example, I have this set of labels: "wood", "plastic" and I would like to set the color for "Wood" to brown and  every time that category shows up in a graph.

Here is my current code:

```
switch(attrs.type) {
        case 'pie': return $.extend(config, {
            seriesColors:['#4bb2c5', '#EAA228', '#c5b47f', '#579575', '#839557', '#958c12', '#953579', '#4b5de4', '#d8b83f', '#ff5800', '#0085cc', '#c747a3', '#cddf54', '#FBD178', '#26B4E3', '#bd70c7'],
            seriesDefaults: {
                shadow: false,
                renderer: $.jqplot.PieRenderer,
                rendererOptions: {
                    showDataLabels: true,
                    varyBarColor: true
                },
            }
        }
        );
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dataLabels`, `seriesColors` and `labels` property(of legends) to achieve this.

Refer below for jqPLot docs

- [dataLabels](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-pieRenderer-js.html#$.jqplot.PieRenderer.dataLabels)
- [seriesColors](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqPlotOptions-txt.html)
- [legend labels](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#Legend.labels)

I have created a fiddle. Is this something that you are looking out for?
Follow this link: [jqPLot Pie Chart - Series labels and colors](http://jsfiddle.net/anish_nair/ehbwd970/1/)

Regards,

Anish